# How do I add up multiple cells in Google Sheets with difference descriptions in the cell?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I add up multiple Expense Types from this Pivot Table onto another sheet?  For example I need to add up Design, Education, Entertainment, Learning, Media, Misc UpWork, Phone/Cable, and Phone Editing but I want the formula to look at the expense type name in order to know what to add up because I will be updating the pivot table monthly and there will be other expense types added.

[image: Image for Reference]

Comment: Please note, questions related to Google Sheets and interacting with Google Sheets should be programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can `QUERY` it out:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(Sheet1!A:B, 
 "select B where A = 'Design'
              or A = 'Education'
              or A = 'Entertainment'
              or A = 'Learning'
              or A = 'Media'
              or A = 'Misc UpWork'
              or A = 'Phone/Cable'
              or A = 'Phone Editing'"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you!  This worked but only if I copy paste values from the Pivot Table that the data is in.  Is there a reason it won't work if I'm using the formula you gave me to get the info from a Pivot Table vs a regular sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QmtSX2oe7ANmOYL95nzr_Bp2ExCgUB6KJG2TFbJtrqs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: On the Feb tab I highlighted in Yellow where I need the total.  The info I need to sum up is on the Pivot Table 2 tab

Comment: @KimberlyHudson did you try it like this? `=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY('Pivot Table 2'!A:B, 
 "select B where A = 'Design'
              or A = 'Education'
              or A = 'Entertainment'
              or A = 'Learning'
              or A = 'Media'
              or A = 'Misc Upwork'
              or A = 'Phone/Cable'
              or A = 'Photo Editing'"))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8xmX.png